# USB keyboard and USB mouse with Mac mini

Tags: keyboard, usb, mac-mini, mouse

I was told by the salesman that I cannot use USB keyboard and mouse with my Mac mini, so I have to use wireless keyboard and mouse.

Is there anything I can do to use USB keyboard/mouse?

Comment: Please do not include the answer in the question, post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Apple's Mac mini is the "budget" line of computers and actually *does not* come with a mouse and keyboard and instead, Apple tells you to "bring your own".

From the current (2017) product page on [Apple.com](http://www.apple.com/mac-mini/):

> Mac mini is an affordable powerhouse that packs the entire Mac
>   experience into a 7.7-inch-square frame. **Just connect your own
>   display, keyboard, and mouse**, and you’re ready to make big things
>   happen.

Nowhere on Apple's site does it state that it "only works with wireless keyboards."

Going all the way to the other end of the timeline, [MacWorld.com](http://www.macworld.com/article/1042446/computers/doublecommand.html) has an article from 2005 that reviews the Mac mini.  In it, it states:

> Apple touts the Mac mini as being compatible with any USB keyboard...

***If you cannot use a USB mouse and/or keyboard on your Mac mini, it's time to do some diagnostics to see if those USB ports are functional.***

Answer (score 4):

I use USB keyboards and mice with my Mac minis by plugging them into the USB ports on the rear of the Mac mini.

Comment: Hm okey I didn't know that it was possible. So it seems I'm scammed..

Comment: @mrbengi "Scammed"? Do you mean just given bad advice?

Comment: No, my seller have said that I cannot use USB keyboard/mouse. But normally, you can trust him. So in fact, my Mac Mini model may not support it...

Comment: @mrbengi  Are you saying that you have never tried plugging in a usb keyboard or mouse yet?

Comment: @mrbengi There are no Mac Mini models that lack support for a USB keyboard and mouse.

Comment: @Tom I had tried plugging with USB and it doesn't work with model A1347 that I used.

Comment: @mrbengi  So I guess you have a broken mini.  You can either try to return it and buy a good one instead, or try to see if it can be repaired.  I have no idea if repair would be possible, better to get a good one if you need usb.

Comment: @mrbengi it's also possible you have a faulty keyboard. But model A1347 is being sold with a USB keyboard here: https://www.amazon.com/Apple-A1347-MC270LL-Intel-320GB/dp/B00AJMDVSW for example.